# Service Host almost always takes almost 100% of CPU

Tags: windows-8

One process on my computer almost always takes almost 100% of CPU
What should I do?

[image]

**upd** I've just tried to reboot and received a blue screen and KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR. I do receive such bluescreen regullary.

Comment: KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR states that the requested page of kernel data from the paging file could not be read into memory. It appears that there are some issues with the hard disk. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559211(v=vs.85).aspx RAM could also be the problem.

Comment: i think KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR is by accident and this problems are not connected. because problem with "73%" was just reproduced but when rebooting i didn't see `KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR`.