# Service Host: Local Service (No Impersonation) taking CPU Usage to 100%

Tags: windows-8, services

What is this service doing that it seems to take >90% of CPU? This happened occasioanlly when I used my notebook, and I noticed it when suddenly the fan became loud. I tried to google but some said it's related to Windows Media Player... Does anyone know what is it that this service doing and why it takes CPU Usage so high?

[image: Impersonator]

The column from left to right: CPU (91.8%) | Memory | Disk | Network

Comment: Its likely connected to the [HDD](http://superuser.com/questions/520029/service-host-almost-always-takes-almost-100-of-cpu?rq=1)

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the CPU usage and analyze it with WPA: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD. If you're unsure, zip and upload (OneDrive) the ETL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Got to services.msc
- Stop Windows Media player Network sharing service
- Disable the same service by going to proprties.